# How does my use of gather in a ggplot call affect the output?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the mtcars data set in R and am trying to use ggplot to plot every variable against mpg in a facet grid. I also want each individual graph to be split into different colours by the am variable .

I have successfully made the plot I want to using the below code.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(tidyr)
data(mtcars)
mtcars %>%
    gather(-mpg, -am, key = "key", value = "value", convert = TRUE, factor_key = TRUE) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = value, y = mpg, color = factor(am))) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free")
```

However if I had first converted some of the variables from num to factor the result is a different looking graph and I am struggling to understand why. Here is the second plot after having converted some variables to factors.

```r
data(mtcars)
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl)
mtcars$vs <- factor(mtcars$vs)
levels(mtcars$vs) = c("V", "S")
mtcars$am <- factor(mtcars$am)
levels(mtcars$am) = c("A", "M")
mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear)
mtcars$carb <- factor(mtcars$carb)

mtcars %>%
    gather(-mpg, -am, key = "key", value = "value", convert = TRUE, factor_key = TRUE) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = value, y = mpg, color = factor(am))) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free")
```

Notice how the plot is different (e.g. the trend for hp is in the opposite direction). I think it may be something to do with how R is using gather from tidyr since I receive and error message in the call to gather (the 2nd instance) saying:

```r
Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables;
they will be dropped
```

Would love some light shed on this!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I would look at the dataframe generated from your `gather` call before plotting it if you think there are issues.

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl)
mtcars$vs <- factor(mtcars$vs)
levels(mtcars$vs) = c("V", "S")
mtcars$am <- factor(mtcars$am)
levels(mtcars$am) = c("A", "M")
mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear)
mtcars$carb <- factor(mtcars$carb)
mtcars <- mtcars %>%
    gather(-mpg, -am, key = "key", value = "value", convert = TRUE, factor_key = TRUE)

glimpse(mtcars)
# Observations: 576
Variables: 4
# $ mpg <dbl> ...
# $ am <fct> ...
# $ key <chr> ...
# $ value <chr> ...
```

Your value column is a character vector. If you plot just `hp` against `mpg` you can see what's happened:

```
mtcars %>% filter(key == "hp") %>% ggplot(aes(x = value, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

It sorts the character vector "alphabetically" (e.g., 100 is lower than 90 because it starts with `1`).

You could convert the `value` column back to numeric, although you'll add some NAs to the `vs` variable.

```
mtcars$value <- as.numeric(mtcars$value)
mtcars %>% filter(key == "hp") %>% ggplot(aes(x = value, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
```

[image: output2]

I suppose the salient questions are: a) should you compare categorical and numerical variables in the same plot?, and b) if so, do they really need to be categorical? That is, is there anything wrong with your first plot? I'm definitely open to opinions on this.